# DevExtreme React Grid

Tags: javascript, reactjs, devexpress, material-ui, react-grid-layout

Anyone know how to change the fontSize of the TableHeaderRow in a DevExtreme React Grid?

Here's an example of code from the website (https://devexpress.github.io/devextreme-reactive/react/grid/demos/featured/data-editing/) that I have been working with

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import {
  SortingState, EditingState, PagingState,
  IntegratedPaging, IntegratedSorting,
} from '@devexpress/dx-react-grid';
import {
  Grid,
  Table, TableHeaderRow, TableEditRow, TableEditColumn,
  PagingPanel, DragDropProvider, TableColumnReordering,
} from '@devexpress/dx-react-grid-material-ui';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
import Dialog from '@material-ui/core/Dialog';
import DialogActions from '@material-ui/core/DialogActions';
import DialogContent from '@material-ui/core/DialogContent';
import DialogContentText from '@material-ui/core/DialogContentText';
import DialogTitle from '@material-ui/core/DialogTitle';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';
import Input from '@material-ui/core/Input';
import Select from '@material-ui/core/Select';
import MenuItem from '@material-ui/core/MenuItem';
import TableCell from '@material-ui/core/TableCell';

import DeleteIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Delete';
import EditIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Edit';
import SaveIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Save';
import CancelIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Cancel';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

import { ProgressBarCell } from '../../../theme-sources/material-ui/components/progress-bar-cell';
import { HighlightedCell } from '../../../theme-sources/material-ui/components/highlighted-cell';
import { CurrencyTypeProvider } from '../../../theme-sources/material-ui/components/currency-type-provider';
import { PercentTypeProvider } from '../../../theme-sources/material-ui/components/percent-type-provider';

import {
  generateRows,
  globalSalesValues,
} from '../../../demo-data/generator';

const styles = theme => ({
  lookupEditCell: {
    paddingTop: theme.spacing.unit * 0.875,
    paddingRight: theme.spacing.unit,
    paddingLeft: theme.spacing.unit,
  },
  dialog: {
    width: 'calc(100% - 16px)',
  },
  inputRoot: {
    width: '100%',
  },
});

const AddButton = ({ onExecute }) => (
  <div style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>
    <Button
      color="primary"
      onClick={onExecute}
      title="Create new row"
    >
      New
    </Button>
  </div>
);

const EditButton = ({ onExecute }) => (
  <IconButton onClick={onExecute} title="Edit row">
    <EditIcon />
  </IconButton>
);

const DeleteButton = ({ onExecute }) => (
  <IconButton onClick={onExecute} title="Delete row">
    <DeleteIcon />
  </IconButton>
);

const CommitButton = ({ onExecute }) => (
  <IconButton onClick={onExecute} title="Save changes">
    <SaveIcon />
  </IconButton>
);

const CancelButton = ({ onExecute }) => (
  <IconButton color="secondary" onClick={onExecute} title="Cancel changes">
    <CancelIcon />
  </IconButton>
);

const commandComponents = {
  add: AddButton,
  edit: EditButton,
  delete: DeleteButton,
  commit: CommitButton,
  cancel: CancelButton,
};

const Command = ({ id, onExecute }) => {
  const CommandButton = commandComponents[id];
  return (
    <CommandButton
      onExecute={onExecute}
    />
  );
};

const availableValues = {
  product: globalSalesValues.product,
  region: globalSalesValues.region,
  customer: globalSalesValues.customer,
};

const LookupEditCellBase = ({
  availableColumnValues, value, onValueChange, classes,
}) => (
  <TableCell
    className={classes.lookupEditCell}
  >
    <Select
      value={value}
      onChange={event => onValueChange(event.target.value)}
      input={(
        <Input
          classes={{ root: classes.inputRoot }}
        />
)}
    >
      {availableColumnValues.map(item => (
        <MenuItem key={item} value={item}>
          {item}
        </MenuItem>
      ))}
    </Select>
  </TableCell>
);
export const LookupEditCell = withStyles(styles, { name: 'ControlledModeDemo' })(LookupEditCellBase);

const Cell = (props) => {
  const { column } = props;
  if (column.name === 'discount') {
    return <ProgressBarCell {...props} />;
  }
  if (column.name === 'amount') {
    return <HighlightedCell {...props} />;
  }
  return <Table.Cell {...props} />;
};

const EditCell = (props) => {
  const { column } = props;
  const availableColumnValues = availableValues[column.name];
  if (availableColumnValues) {
    return <LookupEditCell {...props} availableColumnValues={availableColumnValues} />;
  }
  return <TableEditRow.Cell {...props} />;
};

const getRowId = row => row.id;

class DemoBase extends React.PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      columns: [
        { name: 'product', title: 'Product' },
        { name: 'region', title: 'Region' },
        { name: 'amount', title: 'Sale Amount' },
        { name: 'discount', title: 'Discount' },
        { name: 'saleDate', title: 'Sale Date' },
        { name: 'customer', title: 'Customer' },
      ],
      tableColumnExtensions: [
        { columnName: 'amount', align: 'right' },
      ],
      rows: generateRows({
        columnValues: { id: ({ index }) => index, ...globalSalesValues },
        length: 12,
      }),
      sorting: [],
      editingRowIds: [],
      addedRows: [],
      rowChanges: {},
      currentPage: 0,
      deletingRows: [],
      pageSize: 0,
      pageSizes: [5, 10, 0],
      columnOrder: ['product', 'region', 'amount', 'discount', 'saleDate', 'customer'],
      currencyColumns: ['amount'],
      percentColumns: ['discount'],
    };
    const getStateDeletingRows = () => {
      const { deletingRows } = this.state;
      return deletingRows;
    };
    const getStateRows = () => {
      const { rows } = this.state;
      return rows;
    };

    this.changeSorting = sorting => this.setState({ sorting });
    this.changeEditingRowIds = editingRowIds => this.setState({ editingRowIds });
    this.changeAddedRows = addedRows => this.setState({
      addedRows: addedRows.map(row => (Object.keys(row).length ? row : {
        amount: 0,
        discount: 0,
        saleDate: new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0],
        product: availableValues.product[0],
        region: availableValues.region[0],
        customer: availableValues.customer[0],
      })),
    });
    this.changeRowChanges = rowChanges => this.setState({ rowChanges });
    this.changeCurrentPage = currentPage => this.setState({ currentPage });
    this.changePageSize = pageSize => this.setState({ pageSize });
    this.commitChanges = ({ added, changed, deleted }) => {
      let { rows } = this.state;
      if (added) {
        const startingAddedId = rows.length > 0 ? rows[rows.length - 1].id + 1 : 0;
        rows = [
          ...rows,
          ...added.map((row, index) => ({
            id: startingAddedId + index,
            ...row,
          })),
        ];
      }
      if (changed) {
        rows = rows.map(row => (changed[row.id] ? { ...row, ...changed[row.id] } : row));
      }
      this.setState({ rows, deletingRows: deleted || getStateDeletingRows() });
    };
    this.cancelDelete = () => this.setState({ deletingRows: [] });
    this.deleteRows = () => {
      const rows = getStateRows().slice();
      getStateDeletingRows().forEach((rowId) => {
        const index = rows.findIndex(row => row.id === rowId);
        if (index > -1) {
          rows.splice(index, 1);
        }
      });
      this.setState({ rows, deletingRows: [] });
    };
    this.changeColumnOrder = (order) => {
      this.setState({ columnOrder: order });
    };
  }

  render() {
    const {
      classes,
    } = this.props;
    const {
      rows,
      columns,
      tableColumnExtensions,
      sorting,
      editingRowIds,
      addedRows,
      rowChanges,
      currentPage,
      deletingRows,
      pageSize,
      pageSizes,
      columnOrder,
      currencyColumns,
      percentColumns,
    } = this.state;

    return (
      <Paper>
        <Grid
          rows={rows}
          columns={columns}
          getRowId={getRowId}
        >
          <SortingState
            sorting={sorting}
            onSortingChange={this.changeSorting}
          />
          <PagingState
            currentPage={currentPage}
            onCurrentPageChange={this.changeCurrentPage}
            pageSize={pageSize}
            onPageSizeChange={this.changePageSize}
          />

          <IntegratedSorting />
          <IntegratedPaging />

          <CurrencyTypeProvider for={currencyColumns} />
          <PercentTypeProvider for={percentColumns} />

          <EditingState
            editingRowIds={editingRowIds}
            onEditingRowIdsChange={this.changeEditingRowIds}
            rowChanges={rowChanges}
            onRowChangesChange={this.changeRowChanges}
            addedRows={addedRows}
            onAddedRowsChange={this.changeAddedRows}
            onCommitChanges={this.commitChanges}
          />

          <DragDropProvider />

          <Table
            columnExtensions={tableColumnExtensions}
            cellComponent={Cell}
          />

          <TableColumnReordering
            order={columnOrder}
            onOrderChange={this.changeColumnOrder}
          />

          <TableHeaderRow showSortingControls />
          <TableEditRow
            cellComponent={EditCell}
          />
          <TableEditColumn
            width={120}
            showAddCommand={!addedRows.length}
            showEditCommand
            showDeleteCommand
            commandComponent={Command}
          />
          <PagingPanel
            pageSizes={pageSizes}
          />
        </Grid>

        <Dialog
          open={!!deletingRows.length}
          onClose={this.cancelDelete}
          classes={{ paper: classes.dialog }}
        >
          <DialogTitle>
Delete Row
          </DialogTitle>
          <DialogContent>
            <DialogContentText>
              Are you sure to delete the following row?
            </DialogContentText>
            <Paper>
              <Grid
                rows={rows.filter(row => deletingRows.indexOf(row.id) > -1)}
                columns={columns}
              >
                <CurrencyTypeProvider for={currencyColumns} />
                <PercentTypeProvider for={percentColumns} />
                <Table
                  columnExtensions={tableColumnExtensions}
                  cellComponent={Cell}
                />
                <TableHeaderRow />
              </Grid>
            </Paper>
          </DialogContent>
          <DialogActions>
            <Button onClick={this.cancelDelete} color="primary">
Cancel
            </Button>
            <Button onClick={this.deleteRows} color="secondary">
Delete
            </Button>
          </DialogActions>
        </Dialog>
      </Paper>
    );
  }
}

export default withStyles(styles, { name: 'ControlledModeDemo' })(DemoBase);
```

The font size of the text labelling the columns (e.g. product, region, amount) is fixed, and I see no parameters that can change it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I think there are a few ways around this, the way I have used is having a fully controlled component.

Looks a little like this

```
<TableHeaderRow cellComponent={this.ExampleHeaderCell} />
```

Where ExampleHeaderCell is a component that would look something like this

```
 ExampleHeaderCell = (props: any) => (<TableHeaderRow.Cell
                className={exampleClass}
                {...props}
                key={column.name}
                getMessage={() => column.title}
            />)
```

From there you can pass it a class as shown with exampleClass

You can take this further and have it customised for a particular column.

```
ExampleHeaderCells = (props: any) => {
    const exampleClass = css({ backgroundColor: "blue" })
    const { column } = props
    if (column.name === "name") {
        return (
            <TableHeaderRow.Cell
                className={exampleClass}
                {...props}
                key={column.name}
                getMessage={() => column.title}
            />
        )
    }
    return <TableHeaderRow.Cell {...props} key={column.name} getMessage={() => column.title} />
}
```

The example above is returning a specific cell with the exampleClass if the column name is equal to "name". Otherwise it just returns the regular TableHeaderRow.Cell

Comment: Thank you. It helped me to understand. 
Do yo know if there is anyway to change text color of a heading of sorted column?

Comment: Yes for sure :) . You would probably need to be using the controlled sorting method so that you can keep track of which column is currently sorted. You would also need to override the TableHeaderCells like in the example above. Would have to manage the state of the currently sorted above both so you could then pass the currently sorted state to the headercomponent.